# Multiple orderby parameters in pre_get_posts() action

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts

Referencing [@Otto's response](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/Multiple-orderby-and-order-options-in-WP-Query-tp36938p36944.html) to a question I also had about ordering by multiple fields, here is what he said:

> Can't do it with a naive WP_Query. Use the posts_orderby filter to add 
>   your own ordering string.

```
function my_order($orderby) { 
    global $wpdb; 
    return "{$wpdb->posts.post_author} ASC, {$wpdb->posts.post_date} DESC"; 
} 
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_order' ); 

$blah = new WP_Query(...); 

remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_order' );
```

> -Otto

This appears to be the way it would be done in a new call to WP_Query --> how would I go about this same thing in a `pre_get_posts()` action with two meta fields, with a default sort to?:

```
function mouldings_sort($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_tax(array('wood_types','profile_categories','combination_categories'))) {

        $query->set('meta_key', '_mouldings_dimensions_height');
        $query->set('order', 'DESC');
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
    }

}
add_action('pre_get_posts','mouldings_sort');
```

I had previously tried simply adding in another meta field like so:

```
$query->set('meta_key', array('_mouldings_dimensions_height', '_mouldings_dimension_width'));
$query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
```

with a default sortback of `title` as so:

```
 $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num title');
```

but it doesn't look like `meta_key` can accept arrays and my `title` fallback goes back to Otto's original response on the matter. Any help would be a greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: take a look at this approach http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67391/2487

Comment: Any progress on that one?

Answer (score 2):

Never forget that there're actually **two filters**

```
// Add additional query args that are allowed by the API by default
pre_get_posts
// Modify the query herself
posts_clauses
// Inspect the resulting string - test this one in for e.g. phpMyAdmin
posts_request
```

So everything you can achieve using the `pre_get_posts` filter should be done there. The rest should be modified using the `posts_clauses` (or one of the more specific filters before).

```
// Modify the original query parts
function wpse70214_pre_get_posts( $query )
{
    var_dump( $query );
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse70214_pre_get_posts' );

// Modify the resulting query string parts
function wpse70214_posts_clauses( $pieces )
{
    var_dump( $pieces );
    return $pieces;
}
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse70214_posts_clauses' );

// Then check the result
function wpse70214_posts_request( $query_string )
{
    var_dump( $query_string );
    return $query_string;
}
add_action( 'posts_request', 'wpse70214_posts_request' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes like Otto said you can't have a secondary `ORDER BY` clause without a a custom `posts_orderby` filter.  If you need to know what query your on a la "pre_get_posts" you can create a function that adds the orderby filter to posts_orderby and call it from pre_get_posts.

```
/**
 * Posts orderby filter.  The filter will be added using pre_get_posts outside the class
 *  using the pre_get_posts action allows us to do checks for what page etc...
 * @return string, new MySQL ORDER BY clause
 */
function wpse_order_by() {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->prepare( "$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC, post_title DESC" );
}

/**
 * Pre get posts filter for adding secondary fall back ORDER BY clause to MySql query
 * @uses remove_filter(), This filter removes itself after it runs to prevent it from affecting  other queries on the same page.
 * @uses add_filter()
 * @param object|array $query the current $query object
 */
function wpse_post_order_pre( $query ) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_tax(array('wood_types','profile_categories','combination_categories'))) {

    /** remove_filter() is used to prevent this affecting additional queries on the page */
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse_order_by' );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_post_order_pre' );
```

Comment: Hi Chris - I really appreciate the reply. [Here](http://pastebin.com/yxepQzwQ) is the entire `pre_get_posts()` filter I am current using. Did I add that in correctly? Currently getting the [following](http://pastebin.com/s08m05Nc) DB error on an unrelated WP_Query (which is odd since I'm running a check to make sure we're only effecting the main query). Any thoughts on that? In addition, does this address being able to add-in a secondary order as another meta field, `_mouldings_dimensions_width` and THEN eventually fall-back to the title? Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: It needs to be in its' own function instead of mixed with your current pre_get_posts.  If the remove_filter doesn't run the action will get added to every query on the page.  You will get an unknown column postmeta.meta_value MySql error if it runs on any query that is NOT a meta_query because it needs the INNER join on postmeta to work.  Use debug bar so you can see what the MySql looks like to debug this.

Comment: Thanks Chris - SQL error on the page is `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'galleries' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC, post_title DESC LIMIT 0, 2` which means it's still reaching outside of the main query. Would this be more the plugin adding the `galleries` post type not resetting the query correctly? Any docs on what `meta_value+0` is, I'll obviously take the answer ;) but would love to know what that is as well. Thanks.

Comment: That query, [shown here](http://pastebin.com/pM9gERSw) does appear to reset the query properly (generating from a widget).

Comment: Those errors are because remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ ); is not working or is being fired to early.  You can try setting the priority to 99999 to make sure it fires last.

Comment: Setting the priority higher didn't work - I know we're going back 'n forth here a bit, so I'll try a few things on my end and report back my findings. Thanks again for sticking with me on this.