# Ordering custom post type by multiple custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, meta-query, order

I was wondering if you'd be able to help with an issue i'm having?

I have implemented a fix that you came up with in this post:
[How to order custom post type by multiple custom fields?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67387/how-to-order-custom-post-type-by-multiple-custom-fields/67391#67391) however when I add the filter no posts are being displayed.

What I'm trying to achieve is to order a league table by points and then by goal difference.

This is my function in functions.php

```
function orderbyreplace($orderby ) {
global $wpdb;
return str_replace($wpdb->prefix.'postmeta.meta_value', 'mt1.meta_value, mt2.meta_value ASC', $orderby);
}
```

And here's the query in my template file

```
$args = array(
              'post_type'=>'standings',
              'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
              'meta_key' => '_pts',
              'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => '_pts',
                        'value' => '0',
                        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                        'compare' => '!='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => '_dif',
                        'value' => '0',
                        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                        'compare' => '!='
                    )
                ),
            );

            add_filter('posts_orderby','orderbyreplace');
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            remove_filter('posts_orderby','orderbyreplace');
```

If you could spare a few minutes of your time to have a look over this and make any suggestions you may have and point anything out where I might have gone wrong that would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I've changed the code to the following and it is know returning posts however it's only ordering them by the first meta_key and ignores the other.

```
function orderbyreplace($orderby) {
                global $wpdb;
                return str_replace($wpdb->prefix.'postmeta.meta_value_num', 'mt1.meta_value, mt2.meta_value DESC', $orderby);
            }

            $args = array(
              'post_type'=>'standings',
              'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
              'meta_key' => '_pts',
              'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => '_pts',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => '_dif',
                    )
                ),
            );

            add_filter('posts_orderby','orderbyreplace');
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            remove_filter('posts_orderby','orderbyreplace');
```

Many thanks,

Ben

Comment: Did you try the [*accepted* answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67434/1685)?

Comment: Yep I tried that as well but the same thing happens, no posts are being pulled through.