# Problem querying Custom post type by custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

I have created a custom post type called jugadores in a wordpress site, this custom post type includes custom meta fields for storing custom fields, this include things like the number of the player, name etc, I would like to use this information y a query that will present all the players in a page section, but it is not working

```
            <?php 

        function inicializar_post_jugadores()
        {
            $etiquetas = array(
                'name' => 'Jugadores',
                'singular_name' => 'Jugadores',
                'add_new' => 'Agregar Jugador o Cuerpo Técnico',
                'all_items' => 'Toda la plantilla',
                'add_new_item' => 'Agregar Jugador o cuerpo Técnico',
                'edit_item' => 'Editar Jugador o Cuerpo Técnico',
                'new_item' => 'Nuevo Jugador o Cuerpo Técnico',
                'view_item' => 'Ver Jugador o Cuerpo Técnico',
                'search_item'=> 'Buscar Jugador o Cuerpo Técnico',
                'not_found' => 'No se encontro el perfil',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No hay perfiles en la papelera',
                'parent_item_colon' => 'Lista Padre'
            );

            $argumentos = array(
                'labels' => $etiquetas,
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => false, 
                'publicly_queryable' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => true,
                'capabality_type' => 'post',
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions' ),
                'menu_position' => 5,
            
                'exclude_from_search' => false      
            );

            register_post_type( 'jugadores', $argumentos);
        }

        add_action( 'init', 'inicializar_post_jugadores');



        function agregar_tipo_post_jugadores_a_categorias($query) 
        {
        if( is_category() ) 
        {
            $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
            
            if($post_type)
            {
                $post_type = $post_type;
            }
            else
            {     
                $post_type = array('nav_menu_item', 'post', 'jugadores'); 
            }
            $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
            return $query;
        }
        }


        add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'agregar_tipo_post_jugadores_a_categorias');



        function agregar_campos_personalizados()
        {
            add_meta_box
            ( 
                'mis_campos', 
                'Campos', 
                'drwCampos_personalizados_jugadores', 
                'jugadores', 
                'normal', 
                'high' 
            );
        }

        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'agregar_campos_personalizados');


        function drwCampos_personalizados_jugadores()
        {
            global $post;
            $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mis_campos', true ); 
            
            ?>

                <input type="hidden" name="campos_post_jugadores" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( basename(__FILE__) ); ?>">

            <section id="Datos-personales">
                <div class="text-left">
                    <h1 class="font-weight-bolder">Datos Personales</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 py-2">
                        <label for="">Nombres</label>
                        <input type="text" name="mis_campos[nombre_jugador]" id="mis_campos[nombre_jugador]" class="w-100 form-control" value="<?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['nombre_jugador'])){ echo $meta['nombre_jugador']; } ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 py-2">
                        <label for="mis_campos[apellido_jugador]">Apellidos</label>
                        <input id="mis_campos[apellido_jugador]" type="text" name="mis_campos[apellido_jugador]" class="w-100 form-control" value="<?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['apellido_jugador'])){ echo $meta['apellido_jugador']; } ?>"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 py-2"> 
                        <label for="mis_campos[fecha_nacimiento]">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                        <input id="mis_campos[fecha_nacimiento]" type="date" name="mis_campos[fecha_nacimiento]" class="w-100 form-control" value="<?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['fecha_nacimiento'])){ echo $meta['fecha_nacimiento']; } ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 py-2"> 
                        <label for="mis_campos[fecha_nacimiento]">Peso Actual Libras</label>
                        <input id="mis_campos[peso_jugador]" type="number" name="mis_campos[peso_jugador]" class="w-100 form-control" value="<?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['peso_jugador'])){ echo $meta['peso_jugador']; } ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 py-2"> 
                        <label for="mis_campos[altura_nacimiento]">Estatura Metros</label>
                        <input id="mis_campos[altura_jugador]" type="number" name="mis_campos[altura_jugador]" class="w-100 form-control" min="0" max="4" value="<?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['altura_jugador'])){ echo $meta['altura_jugador']; } ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 py-2">
                        <label for="mis_campos[lugar_origin_jugador]">Lugar de Nacimiento</label>
                        <input id="mis_campos[lugar_origin_jugador]" type="text" name="mis_campos[lugar_origin_jugador]" class="w-100 form-control" value="<?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['lugar_origin_jugador'])){ echo $meta['lugar_origin_jugador']; } ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label for="mis_campos[frase_jugador]">Frase o comentario</label>
                        <input id="mis_campos[frase_jugador]" type="text" name="mis_campos[frase_jugador]" class="w-100 form-control" value="<?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['frase_jugador'])){ echo $meta['frase_jugador']; } ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="text-left">
                    <h1 class="font-weight-bolder">Redes Sociales</h1>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label class="text-center" for="mis_campos[facebook_jugador]">Página de Facebook</label>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-2x" style="color: #395185; margin-top:"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input id="mis_campos[facebook_jugador]" type="text" name="mis_campos[facebook_jugador]" class="w-100 form-control" value="<?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['facebook_jugador'])){ echo $meta['facebook_jugador']; } ?>" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label class="text-center" for="mis_campos[twitter_jugador]">Página de Twitter</label>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x" style="color: #08bbee; margin-top:"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input id="mis_campos[twitter_jugador]" type="text" name="mis_campos[twitter_jugador]" class="w-100 form-control" value="<?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['twitter_jugador'])){ echo $meta['twitter_jugador']; } ?>" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label  class="text-center" for="mis_campos[instagram_jugador]">Página de Instagram</label>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x" style="color: #5f46b9; margin-top:"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input id="mis_campos[instagram_jugador]" type="text" name="mis_campos[instagram_jugador]" class="w-100 form-control" value="<?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['instagram_jugador'])){ echo $meta['instagram_jugador']; } ?>" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label class="text-center" for="mis_campos[youtube_jugador]">Canal de Youtube</label>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x" style="color: #ff0000; margin-top:"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input id="mis_campos[youtube_jugador]" type="text" name="mis_campos[youtube_jugador]" class="w-100 form-control" value="<?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['youtube_jugador'])){ echo $meta['youtube_jugador']; } ?>" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <hr>
            <section id="Datos-jugador" class="mt-3">
                <h1 class="text-left font-weight-bolder">Datos Como Jugador</h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
                        <label for="mis_campos[numero_jugador]">Número como Jugador</label>
                        <input id="mis_campos[numero_jugador]" type="number" name="mis_campos[numero_jugador]" class="form-control w-100" min="00" max="99" value="<?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['numero_jugador'])){ echo $meta['numero_jugador']; } ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
                        <label for="mis_campos[fecha_debut]">Fecha de Debut</label>
                        <input id="mis_campos[fecha_debut]" type="date" name="mis_campos[fecha_debut]" class="w-100 form-control" value="<?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['fecha_debut'])){ echo $meta['fecha_debut']; } ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
                        <label for="mis_campos[partidos_jugados]">Partidos Jugados</label>
                        <input id="mis_campos[partidos_jugados]" type="number" name="mis_campos[partidos_jugados]" class="form-control w-100" min="0" value="<?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['partidos_jugados'])){ echo $meta['partidos_jugados']; } ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label for="mis_campos[jugador_titular]">Jugador Titular</label>
                        <input id="mis_campos[jugador_titular]" type="checkbox" name="mis_campos[jugador_titular]" class="d-block mx-auto form-control" <?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['jugador_titular'])){ echo 'checked'; } ?>>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label for="cars">Posición Jugador</label>
                        <select name="mis_campos[posicion_jugador]" id="mis_campos[posicion_jugador]" class="form-control w-100" value="">
                        <option value="portero" <?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['posicion_jugador'])){if(strcmp($meta['posicion_jugador'], 'portero') == 0) {echo 'selected';}} ?>>Portero</option>
                        <option value="defensa" <?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['posicion_jugador'])){if(strcmp($meta['posicion_jugador'], 'defensa') == 0) {echo 'selected';}} ?>>Defensa</option>
                        <option value="medio_campista" <?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['posicion_jugador'])){if(strcmp($meta['posicion_jugador'], 'medio_campista') == 0) {echo 'selected';}} ?>>Medio Campista</option>
                        <option value="delantero" <?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['posicion_jugador'])){if(strcmp($meta['posicion_jugador'], 'delantero') == 0) {echo 'selected';}} ?>>Delantero</option>
                        <option value="cuerpo_tecnico" <?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['posicion_jugador'])){if(strcmp($meta['posicion_jugador'],'cuerpo_tecnico') == 0) {echo 'selected';}} ?>>Cuerpo Técnico</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label for="mis_campos[posicion_especializada]">Posicion especializada</label>
                        <input id="mis_campos[posicion_especializada]" type="text" name="mis_campos[posicion_especializada]" class="w-100 form-control" value="<?php if (is_array($meta) && isset($meta['posicion_especializada'])){ echo $meta['posicion_especializada']; } ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>  
            

                <?php
        }

        function guardar_campos_jugadores_personalizados( $post_id ) 
        {
            // verify nonce
            if (isset( $_POST['campos_post_jugadores'])) 
            {
                if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['campos_post_jugadores'], basename(__FILE__) ) ) {
                    return $post_id;
                }
            }

            // check autosave
            if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
                return $post_id;
            }
            // check permissions
            if ( 'page' === $_POST['post_type'] ) {
                if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
                    return $post_id;
                } elseif ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
                    return $post_id;
                }
            }

            $old = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'mis_campos', true );
            $new = $_POST['mis_campos'];

            if ( $new && $new !== $old ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mis_campos', $new );
            } elseif ( '' === $new && $old ) {
                delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'mis_campos', $old );
            }
        }
        add_action( 'save_post', 'guardar_campos_jugadores_personalizados' );

        ?>
```

and this is the query I am trying to use, to fetch  the player whose position in the field is striker or "delantero"

```
                    <?php 

                        $argumentos_consulta = array( 'post_type' => 'jugadores', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC', 'nopaging'=> 'true', 'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'meta_key' => 'posicion_jugador',
                                'meta_value' => 'delantero',
                            ) ));
                        $consulta_jugadores = new WP_Query($argumentos_consulta);
                     
                        if ($consulta_jugadores->have_posts()) 
                        {
                            while ($consulta_jugadores->have_posts()) 
                            {
                                
                                $consulta_jugadores->the_post();
                                $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mis_campos', true);

                                get_template_part( 'template-parts/partes/carta_jugador');
                                                                           
                            }
                        }
          
                ?>
```

and this is another form of the query

$argumentos_consulta = array( 'post_type' => 'jugadores','nopaging'=> 'true', 'meta_key' => 'posicion_jugador', 'meta_value' => 'delantero' );

but all of them result in returning all the custom post without taking into consideration de data on the custom field.

I consulted question like this [How to order custom post type by multiple custom fields?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67387/how-to-order-custom-post-type-by-multiple-custom-fields) where the meta fields are suggested to query the custom fields but in my case those has not worked, so I assume and mistake in the creation of the custom post initialization is happening, but so far I have been able to pin point it,

thank you very much in advance!!